# Does using apps while the iPhone X is plugged in run down the battery health?

Tags: iphone, battery, charging, power

My question is pretty similar to this from a few years ago:
[When plugged in, does the iPhone use the battery or the external source during heavy use?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6624/when-plugged-in-does-the-iphone-use-the-battery-or-the-external-source-during-h)

Basically, I was looking to use my iPhone X with some apps, such as video calling or games, for extended periods of time.
As far I understand, using these while the phone is unplugged will run down the charge on the battery, and charging it up again will use some of the charge cycles that the battery has. My plan to mitigate this was to just use the phone while leaving it plugged in to a wall charger, because I assumed the phone would use power from mains rather than the battery, and thus not run down the battery and use much less or even none of the charge cycles. 
Some sources seem to state the battery will still be used and thus the battery life can still be greatly affected, but others are stating the opposite. Is there any consensus? If I use my phone heavily but plugged in, will I come to find the battery life has been reduced because I overused it?

Please note, I'm NOT considering the situation that say an app is extremely resource intensive on the phone and is actually DISCHARGING while plugged in, mostly because I don't think this situation will happen.

Thanks for any insights/answers.

Comment: Batteries last as long as they last. Stop worrying about them.

Comment: @Tetsujin While I realize this and kind of accept it, I'd rather not artificially run down a batteries lifespan, especially if it can be helped.

Comment: You can’t artificially  run down a battery in this manner.  They are susceptible  to temperature extremes and impacts.  The physics of moving electrons into and out of the battery doesn’t change whether you have it plugged in or not.

Comment: “Some sources say this” and “some sources say that” isn’t helpful.  Who are these sources?  People on Reddit?  Did they cite bona fide sources or other posters on a discussion forum somewhere?